# Why '| count' doesn't work after 'as' operator

Tags: kql

Seems the '| count' expression works unexpectedly on a tabular expression bind with 'as' operator. This query returned 100 record instead of 1 record:

```
traces
| take 100 | as traces100;
traces100 
| count
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it differently:

```
let traces100 = traces | take 100;
traces100 
| count
```

It's because `as` and `let` are different:

- `let` statements (which is what you need) bind names to expressions. For the rest of the scope, where the let statement appears, the name can be used to refer to its bound value. See more details in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/letstatement).
- `as` (which is what you tried to use) bind a name to the operator's input tabular expression, thus allowing the query to reference the value of the tabular expression multiple times without breaking the query and binding a name through the let statement. See more details in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/asoperator).

Comment: Thank you Slavik! can you please clarify what's the difference? According to the official documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/asoperator  the as operation is a syntax for binding a name to a tabular expression

Comment: I've edited the answer to contain an explanation about the difference between `as` and `let`. If this helps, please accept the answer. If you still need more info, let me know and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: Thanks Slavik, I have a cx using this pattern and I need to make sure I understand the scenario correct- can you please specify a scenario where you need to use the "| as" operator over the 'take' operator ?  Also, if '| as' binds to a tabular expression, it still should be a valid syntax to use <tabular expression> | count, isn't it ?

Comment: `let` binds a tabular result to a name in a separate statement (that should be followed by a `;`). While the `as` operator is used inside a query. The docs contain all the information you're looking for. An example for when `as` is useful: `datatable(n:real) [ 22, 16, 7, 90, 16, ] | as T | extend PercentOfTotalSum = round(100.0 * n / toscalar(T | summarize sum(n)), 2)` - while we could've achieved the same with `let`, it would be slightly less intuitive to read.